# input check box need to be in checked at first in ng2

Tags: angular, checkbox

This below is that i am expecting to be evaluated,but,this input checkbox need to be in ticked (visually) condition when its all loaded.
But, as of now, it is not happening. on this code, my functionality working fine, additionally, i need this update on this checkbox in ng2. On loading of all checkboxes need to be in ticked condition(visually, true in technical), if i change the value that should be updated to ngModel.

Any clue, pls?

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{{item.file.name}}" [(ngModel)]="item['checked']" id="myCheck" (change)="itemRemovelist(item, item['checked'])">
```

Comment: what is the component code ? update the relevant codes. to make more specific.

Comment: Hi, my aim is to make all the check boxes to be made true.. that is the only thing right now is not happening...

Comment: @User123 Did this work?

Answer (score 1):

Add a checked attribute to your checkbox [checked]="item['checked']". So if your item checked value is true onload the checkbox will be checked. Hope this helps you.